# "arm login" using minicom to access beagleboard XM

Tags: ubuntu, beagleboard

So I'm not quite sure what is going on here. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and running minicom to (ostensibly) connect serially a beagleboard XM which I'm pretty sure is running Angstrom linux.

I can succesfully connect via minicom to the BBXM, but after it is done booting I am faced with the following:

```
arm login:
Password:
```

I've tried passing 'root' as well as my ubuntu username as well as no password and my ubuntu password.

The BBXM runs on an arm processor, so I'm inclined to believe that this login is somehow connected to the beaglebone, but I can't seem to find any documentation indicating what, other than root, it might be.

Answer (score 1):

Try `ubuntu` as user and `temppwd` as password.

Answer (score 0):

I was installing ubuntu-saucy-13.10-armhf-3.8.13-bone30 on BeagleBone Black and logged in as user **ubuntu** and the password was **ubuntu**